# How to fill two menu item in titlebar

Tags: android, xml

How to fill two menu item in title bar. I want to create two menu items (save and cancel) in title bar. how to do that?
I'm trying to create a menu as shown below
[image]

Comment: you mean two titles on toolbar or menu item, the image represents showing two items in toolbar

Comment: It's not menu item in image you have put!,, it's viewpage with tab layout.

Comment: it's not menu item nor tablayout, it;s custom toolbar with two textview or button. you need to create custom toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

in linear layout with horizontal orientation Add two button inside toolbar and give android:layout_weight="1" to each....

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on toolbar this will help you

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>



<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_save"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: then this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Create custom `Toolbar` where you can put elements with required `layout_gravity`. 
See this post [Center align right aligned button on Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265072/center-align-right-aligned-button-on-action-bar/45265154#45265154).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by setting Button parameters as

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:layout_width="0dp"  
android:weight="1"
```

do this in both button